# Null check operator used on a null value error on go_router deep link pop action

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a Flutter application -using Navigator 2.0 with go_router- with nested navigation on the bottom navigation bar, and 3 sub-route on the Home route: Single Post, Single Category, and Single Tag.

When I tried to open a single post URL on the browser, the deep link worked, and it opened the Single Post page on the app. But then, when I clicked the page's back button or the android back-gesture, it has thrown a _CastError: Null check operator used on a null value, and the Home page is not displayed.
What's wrong here, and how can I solve this?

Here is the source code: https://github.com/KweeksNews/kweeksnews_app/tree/develop (branch develop)

Error is thrown on this line: https://github.com/KweeksNews/kweeksnews_app/blob/11747545ab09dfc829ce02094ad16f9735cc39be/lib/core/widgets/navbar.dart#L68

Here is the debug log:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown, building Builder:
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      ScrollPosition.viewportDimension
#1      _PagePosition.getPixelsFromPage
#2      PageController.jumpToPage
#3      _NavBarState.didUpdateWidget
#4      StatefulElement.update
#5      Element.updateChild
#6      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#7      Element.updateChild
#8      ComponentElement.performRebuild
#9      Element.rebuild
#10     StatelessElement.update
#11     Element.updateChild
#12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#13     Element.updateChild
#14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#15     Element.updateChild
#16     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#17     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#18     Element.rebuild
#19     StatefulElement.update
#20     Element.updateChild
#21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#22     Element.updateChild
#23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#24     Element.updateChild
#25     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#26     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#27     Element.rebuild
#28     StatefulElement.update
#29     Element.updateChild
#30     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#31     Element.rebuild
#32     StatelessElement.update
#33     Element.updateChild
#34     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#35     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#36     Element.rebuild
#37     StatefulElement.update
#38     Element.updateChild
#39     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#40     Element.updateChild
#41     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#42     Element.updateChild
#43     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#44     Element.rebuild
#45     ProxyElement.update
#46     _InheritedNotifierElement.update
#47     Element.updateChild
#48     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#49     Element.updateChild
#50     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#51     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#52     Element.rebuild
#53     StatefulElement.update
#54     Element.updateChild
#55     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#56     Element.rebuild
#57     ProxyElement.update
#58     Element.updateChild
#59     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#60     Element.rebuild
#61     ProxyElement.update
#62     Element.updateChild
#63     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#64     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#65     Element.rebuild
#66     StatefulElement.update
#67     Element.updateChild
#68     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#69     Element.rebuild
#70     StatelessElement.update
#71     Element.updateChild
#72     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#73     Element.rebuild
#74     StatelessElement.update
#75     Element.updateChild
#76     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#77     Element.updateChild
#78     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#79     Element.rebuild
#80     ProxyElement.update
#81     Element.updateChild
#82     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#83     Element.rebuild
#84     ProxyElement.update
#85     Element.updateChild
#86     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#87     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#88     Element.rebuild
#89     StatefulElement.update
#90     Element.updateChild
#91     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#92     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#93     Element.rebuild
#94     StatefulElement.update
#95     Element.updateChild
#96     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#97     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#98     Element.rebuild
#99     BuildOwner.buildScope
#100    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#101    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#102    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#103    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#104    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
#108    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#109    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#110    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure about the real cause, but this is what I think happened.

So when the app opened using deep link into `SingePost` page, the app [puts a page containing `Navbar` widget](https://github.com/KweeksNews/kweeksnews_app/blob/5f999595c8aec7e13a79a04db3ae4fbc345595e4/lib/core/router/root_router.dart#L24) first into the page stack, and then [puts the `SinglePost` page](https://github.com/KweeksNews/kweeksnews_app/blob/5f999595c8aec7e13a79a04db3ae4fbc345595e4/lib/core/router/root_router.dart#L70) on top of it. Here it should be noted that the Navbar is not yet rendered by the app.

The [Navbar widget's body is a `PageView`](https://github.com/KweeksNews/kweeksnews_app/blob/5f999595c8aec7e13a79a04db3ae4fbc345595e4/lib/core/widgets/navbar.dart#L85) containing 4 page: `Home`, `Search`, `SavedPosts`, and `Settings`. All four pages are implementing `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to save and keep the scroll position, so that when user is navigating to the other pages and return, the scroll position is persist.

When user is popping out from the SinglePost page, the app then will render the `Navbar` with `Home` as the `PageView`'s selected child (because the [`Navbar` is given with index parameter of 0](https://github.com/KweeksNews/kweeksnews_app/blob/5f999595c8aec7e13a79a04db3ae4fbc345595e4/lib/core/router/root_router.dart#L27)). Now the interesting and confusing part is, the [`didUpdateWidget`](https://github.com/KweeksNews/kweeksnews_app/blob/11747545ab09dfc829ce02094ad16f9735cc39be/lib/core/widgets/navbar.dart#L61) is also called when the `Navbar` is being rendered by the app after user popping out from `SinglePost` page, even no parameter is changed (the `index` still 0). This will trigger a [`_pageController.jumpToPage()`](https://github.com/KweeksNews/kweeksnews_app/blob/11747545ab09dfc829ce02094ad16f9735cc39be/lib/core/widgets/navbar.dart#L68) function, which, I think, in turn will try to render the requested page with the last saved scroll position. But because the page has never been rendered before, the scroll position is `Null`.

To fix this, now [I put a check to make sure the new `index` is different with the current `index`](https://github.com/KweeksNews/kweeksnews_app/blob/5f999595c8aec7e13a79a04db3ae4fbc345595e4/lib/core/widgets/navbar.dart#L66) before calling the `_pageController.jumpToPage()` function, and it worked.